# How to use exported variable into makefile golanf project?

Tags: docker, go, makefile

In our `.gitlab-ci.yml` file this is what I have which gets the appropriate build number depending on branch for me into a variable `TAG`:

```
- test
before_script:
- |
  BUILD_NUM="1.0-${CI_PIPELINE_IID}"
  NORMALIZED_BRANCH="${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME//\//-}"
  REPO_NAME=$(echo ${CI_PROJECT_NAME} | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
  if [ ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} = 'master' ]; then
    export TAG=${BUILD_NUM}
  else
    export TAG="${BUILD_NUM}-${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}"
  fi
```

In our `makefile` for golang project I have below line which registers to consul with the build number:

```
dockercompile:
    GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -mod=readonly -a -ldflags '-s' -installsuffix cgo -o $(BIN_NAME) -ldflags=all="-X github.com/richardwilkes/toolbox/cmdline.AppVersion=1.0 -X github.com/richardwilkes/toolbox/cmdline.BuildNumber=${CI_PIPELINE_IID}" $(MAIN_FILE)
```

How can I use `TAG` variable value in the `cmdline.BuildNumber` value in my above `makefile`? In general I want to follow the same logic for generating build number in my makefile that I have in `.gitlab-ci.yml` and use that value instead of `CI_PIPELINE_IID` in front of `cmdline.BuildNumber`?

I tried using `TAG` variable as it is in my `makefile` but it didn't take the value.

Is this possible to do by any chance?

Comment: How did you mentioned this variable in your makefile?

Comment: I believe that is global variable `CI_PIPELINE_IID` which we can use to get the build number. I don't have that variable declared in that makefile.

Comment: You don't have to declare the variable but use (read) it : https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reference.html#index-_0024_002c-in-variable-reference